# A question in set theory about intersection of two groups.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've reached the answer, that Cn = to all prime numbers, but i really didnt know how to put it on paper and how to prove its right.
I would thank your help.(question below)

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP24e.png)

Comment: It you want people to spend time helping you, the least you could do is to type the problem into your question instead of just posting a picture of text. (Also, there seem to be no _groups_ in that question).

Comment: I have written that question in word, posting it here caused problems with the signs. of course there are groups in that question. look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that $C_n \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $n$ is prime. So we have two things to prove: if $n$ is prime, then $C_n \neq \emptyset$, and that if $n$ is composite, then $C_n = \emptyset$.

For the first statement, assume $n$ is prime. Then we propose that $n\in C_n$. Obviously, $n\in B_n$. Further, if $k < n$, then $n\notin B_k$; for if it were, then we would have $n = ks$ with $1 < k < n$, which is impossible.

For the second, assume $n$ is composite, so $n = pq$ where $1 < p,q < n$. Every element of $B_n$ is a multiple of $n$. But any multiple of $n$ is a multiple of $p$, and so $B_n\subset B_p$. Therefore, $C_n \subset B_n-B_p = \emptyset.$

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much